# API Payout Feature - Authorization Error

Tags: paypal

We are using the [python package for Paypal](https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Python-SDK).

The sandbox key is working fine, but when we switch to the live key, only the payout feature stops working:

Error message:

> {"name":"AUTHORIZATION_ERROR","message":"Authorization error occurred","debug_id":"87fe36dc5d7a7","information_link":""}

I'm assuming it is because this feature is disabled on live accounts and we can request it, we need this feature for our site to work.

heres the code we're using:

```
payout = Payout({
    "sender_batch_header": {
        "sender_batch_id": sender_batch_id,
        "email_subject": "Payment Sent"
    },
    "items": [
        {
            "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
            "amount": {
                "value": '{:.2f}'.format(payout),
                "currency": "GBP"
            },
            "receiver": payee_paypal,
            # "note": "Thank you.",
        },
    ]
})

if payout.create():
    payout_sent.send(promise, payment_id=payout.batch_header.payout_batch_id)
else:
    payment_error.send(promise, reason=payout.error)
```

Comment: sorry guys, thought it was be useful - I got here from the paypal site and assumed paypal people would want the full story.

I've edited it down as I realised mostly non-paypal employee will be reading this

Comment: paypal people are not here.

Comment: Any code or insight in what you are doing would be useful.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have Mass Payments enabled on your PayPal account.  Easiest way to check to see if you do indeed do have Mass Payments enabled is to visit 'my account' area at https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/applications/myapps

If you do have a green check next to Payouts, then you are enabled.  For both RESTful Payouts and Mass Payments.  If you do not, then click through the Enable link.  You kick off an application if you have a US PayPal account.  If not, you'll have to contact your local Customer Support team.

Answer (score 3):

I just spent a few days on this particular problem, and despite everything in all the documentation, none of it is really explicit about what this error means.

The documentation at paypal says that this is an 'Authorization Error' with frustratingly few details.

So, in order to save folks time and frustration and submitting tickets:

1. Payouts need to be enabled for the live environment. They work in the sandbox but until you actually go to the [account status page](https://developer.paypal.com/developer/accountStatus) and click on the link to enable it you will get the AUTHORIZATION_ERROR. It will ask you some questions. Answer them and get ready for them to email you back for a more complete description of how you are going to use their services. This can take a few days.
2. Do all the steps to verify your account as mentioned [here](https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/how-do-i-verify-my-paypal-account-faq444#business).
3. After verifying your account. VERIFY YOUR BANK ACCOUNT! Your PayPal account is labelled as verified once you hook up that bank account and put money in, but you will still get a frustrating AUTHORIZATION_ERROR when trying to use Payouts. Because your bank account is not verified. Do the song and dance to verify your bank account. This can also take a few days. (I don't know what this looks like, they don't let me play with real bank accounts.)
4. Fund your account. Note, you will still get an AUTHORIZATION_ERROR (and not INSUFFICIENT_FUNDS) if your account is insufficiently funded to cover the amount you want to payout plus fees. (At least until you've funded your account the first time, since we've put money in we're getting successes and I've not fully tested all the failure cases in the live environment.)

That's it. But do not be in a hurry, it has been four days since we started trying to test the live environment before we got 'It Worked!' back. Aside from the ticket turn around time. Mind you, you can do a bunch of this in parallel so you might be able to cut it down to two days.

Answer (score 2):

This is Avi from PayPal. I think you are correct in guessing that it is likely an issue with account credentials. Have you tried reaching out to [Paypal's Technical Support](https://ppmts.custhelp.com/) and filing a ticket? To debug this, account credentials would be necessary and it would not be advisable to put live account credentials in public.

Comment: Thanks for that Avi Das, I've tried paypal support they gave me this:

I apologize for the inconvenience and frustration that this issue has caused you. Unfortunately, PayPal Merchant Technical Services does not have the account access available to research this particular issue for you, so you will need to contact the APP review team directly via at https://developer.paypal.com
For instructions about Adaptive Payments, you can visit the page: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/

which lead me here

Comment: Hey so looking at the [docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payouts-overview/), payouts are available everywhere Mass Payments are available. In the [Mass Pay docs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayOverview/) it mentions "First time users should contact their Account Manager or PayPal Customer Support to enable Mass Payments for their PayPal premier or business accounts .... live PayPal accounts must be white listed for the Mass Pay API." Are you using PayPal premier/buisness account and have your account whitelisted?

Comment: @AviDas FYI, take a look at [Revision 1](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27863600/1) of this question for the full transcript that this user had with tech support.

Comment: @PaoloMemoli your account does not have MassPay enabled as Avi Das suggests. Only customer support is able to review your account to enable this feature. Your local support can be reached via phone and the phone number is listed at https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/helpcenter/helphub/home/?action=callus#

Comment: You'll also need to click 'Enable Live Credentials' next to Payouts in your App you created on developer.paypal.com if you haven't already.

Comment: @PP_MTS_Cory, I originally spoke to customer support who put me in touch with paypal.com/mts who [could not help either](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27863600/1).

I have a UK account which I think is causing some problems.

on developer.paypal.com:
-'Enable Live Credentials' points me to helpcenter-call us
-in my app, I have unticked and reticked the 'payout' feature - no joy.

I will try calling them again.

Comment: Understood @PaoloMemoli. When you contact them, let them know that you need to enable Mass Payments on your account.

Comment: @PaoloMemoli Did you ever get the Payouts API enabled? I am having the same problem and am getting the same run around from PayPal (each department keeps referring me to another department). I know MassPay has some restrictions like a minimum monthly income but I'm not sure if these restrictions apply to the Payouts API as well.

Comment: @AviDas did you get the solution for this issue ?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with an Australian account. Has anyone found a solution to this?

Comment: @AviDas, facing same issue and tried with above suggested options but didn't work. Could you pls provide some other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that my PayPal business account was not 100% verified. I followed this guide (business option) and it worked straight away.

https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/how-do-i-verify-my-paypal-account-faq444#business

In a few words, to verify your account simply go to the Profile icon next to "Log out" and complete the steps on your To-do list.